# can we retrieving text messages from iPhone memory in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hello friends  i just want to know that whether we can access or fetch or retrieve the text messages which are in iPhone memory so that we can make a PDF of these text messages.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It would be pretty bad from privacy and security standpoint if you were allowed to do that.